# MATLAB / Simulink: Simulation of a motor control valve

Tags: matlab, simulink

**Problem description:**

I want to simulate a motor control valve (MCV) with Matlab / Simulink. A control-singal (red) controls the MCV, which can take every value between 0% (completely closed) and 100% (completely open):

[image]

I indicated the three different pulses of the input-signal with 1, 2 and 3. As soon as the input-signal changes from 0 to 1 (rising edge), the MCV starts to opens. After time t_Op, the MCV is completely opened. As soon as the input-signal changes from 1 to 0 (falling edge), the valve starts to close. This process is finished after t_Cl. Please note that t_Op and t_Cl do not neccesarily have to be identical.

As you can see in the diagram, the valve gets completely closed after pulse no. 1 (falling edge). However, the width between pulse no. 2 and pulse no. 3 is not long enough to completely close the valve. At the rising edge of pulse no. 3, the valve opens again until it is completely open.

**Question:**

I want to simulate the process described above with Matlab (prefered) or Simulink. I am not a 100% sure how to get started with that problem. I thought about extracting rising / edges from the original system and use this "triggers" to initiate some time-dependent, "sloped"-step-function. Maybe you have some hints for me?

Comment: Although in a different context, the Simulink solution to this problem is achieved in pretty much an identical manner to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190454/matlab-simulink-simulate-filling-and-emptying-of-a-river. "Raining" in that question is your "opening", while "not raining" is your "closing".  You just need to implement the appropriate slope/ramp in the two subsystems to meet your t_op and t_Cl timing requirement.

Comment: I also tried to solve it with two enabled subsystems. However, I don't know how to feed the result (that is the actual position of the valve, e.g. 50%) out of one subsystem into the other (and vice versa) in case of the not completely opened / closed MCV. Inside each subsystem, I can easily define a ramp with min/max values which correspond to the 0% / 100% position of the valve. But these values remain constant over the simulation time and cannot be modified.

Comment: The example in the link shows how to feed the existing value back into the subsystems.  That will work irrespective of the valve position when the direction of the valve changes.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate this, you need to define:
1) Time resolution (0.1 s? 0.01s?)
2) Valve resolution (probably 1%)
3) How to quantize your control signal (If it's just 0 or 1, this is already done; if it's 0V -> 5V, you need to pick which values become `off`, which become `neutral`, and which become `on`

If you quantize your data to 0.1 seconds, and quantize the valve resolution to 1%, you can use something similar to the following (you should be able to fill in the %%% sections yourself

```
pos_initial = 0; % percent, position
t_res = 0.1; % seconds
pos_res = 1; % percent

%%% Declare t_op, t_cl. Solve for open_speed and close_speed If you have t_op and t_res, how can you solve for the open_speed (the amount of opening in a single step? Do the same for close_speed %%%

position(1) = pos_initial; 
for ii = 2:length(input)
    if(input == 1)
        position(ii) = min(position(ii-1) + open_speed, 100); %this makes potition get bigger, but doesn't let it get bigger than 100%
    else
        %%% Looking at the position(ii) line above, how could you do the same for closing to make sure it doesn't go below zero?
    end
end
```